# $L^2$ inner product split over sub-domains in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, inner-products, weak-derivatives

I have a bounded Lipschitz domains $\Omega, \Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\overline{\Omega}=\overline{\Omega}_1 \cup \overline{\Omega}_2$ and $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2=\emptyset$.
Let $u \in H^k(\Omega)$ and $v \in C^\infty(\Omega)$.
When is the following true:

$
(u,v)_{L^2(\Omega)} = (u,v)_{L^2(\Omega_1)} + (u,v)_{L^2(\Omega_2)}
$

From Sobolev embedding theorem, for $k \geq 2$, $u$ is continuous and the above is true.

For $k=-1$, I can construct counter examples (for example, gradient of a discontinuous function).

What about for $k=0$ and $k=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always true, as $\Omega \setminus (\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2)$ can only contain the boundaries of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, which have zero measure due to the regularity assumptions on the domains.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still not entirely convinced. For $u \in L^1$, a set of measure zero could contain a Dirac delta function. Why is it not possible to have a function/distribution in $L^2=H^0$ which is non-zero only on a set of measure zero?

Comment: Functions in $L^p$ are actually equivalence classes of functions that have the same function values with the exception of a zero-measure set. Sets of measure zero do not matter for $L^p$ functions.

Comment: But $\delta_0 \in L^1$ and $\delta_0(x)=0 ~\forall x \neq 0$ but $\lVert \delta_0 \rVert_{L^1} \neq 0$

Comment: My last comment was wrong. It seems $\delta_0 \notin L^1$. $L^p$ only allows functions integrable in the sense of Cauchy principal value. Therefore, as you have pointed out, the result is true for all $u \in L^p$ and therefore for all $u \in H^k$ where $k \geq 0$